# How to Send Mail and access Inbox through STMP/POP Connection in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, sendmail

I need to access Inbox or Sent item  or Send Mail in Blackberry using STMP/POP Connection ?
and Is it possible to Configure Email in Blackberry device Programitically ?

Comment: As for my understanding you cant configure email pragmatically. You can just send mail from your configured mail client gatway.

Comment: u have code of sending mail  and accesing inbox or sent item through SMTP/IMAP  in blackberry..

Comment: Sending mail yes I do have. http://javatechig.com/2011/08/03/sending-email-with-attachment-in-blackberry/

Comment: I want to access inbox through IMAP  not by Blackberry Session. Have code of it?